# Jquery POST image and string with FormData

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-data

This is JQuery part :

```
            $(".btnGorevOlustur").click(function (e) {

                var fileUpload = $(".fileGorevResim").get(0);
                var files = fileUpload.files;
                var dt = new FormData();
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    dt.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                }

                var gPanoID = id;
                var gListeID = gorevListeID;
                var gBaslik = $(".txtGorevBaslik").val();
                var gAciklama = $(".txtareaGorevAciklama").val();
                var gSure = $(".txtGorevSure").val();

                dt.append("gpid", gPanoID);
                dt.append("glid", gListeID);
                dt.append("gbas", gBaslik);
                dt.append("gacik", gAciklama);
                dt.append("gsur", gSure);


                if (gBaslik != null && gBaslik != "" && gAciklama != null && gAciklama != "" && gSure != null && gSure != "") {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "PanoHandler.ashx",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: dt,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
```

And this is handler part :

```
        var gorevBaslik = context.Request.Form["gbas"];
        var gorevAciklama = context.Request.Form["gacik"];
        var gorevSure = context.Request.Form["gsur"];
        var gorevPanoID = context.Request.Form["gpid"];
        var gorevListeID = context.Request.Form["glid"];
        var tarih = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
                string fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/img/panofoto/" + file.FileName + tarih);
                file.SaveAs(fname);
                sgFoto = file.FileName + tarih;
            }
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(gorevBaslik) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(gorevAciklama) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(gorevSure))
        {
            var gorev = new Pano_Gorev
            {
                Baslik = gorevBaslik,
                Aciklama = gorevAciklama,
                GorevSuresi = gorevSure,
                PanoID = Convert.ToInt32(gorevPanoID),
                ListeID = Convert.ToInt32(gorevListeID),
                Resim = sgFoto,
                Olusturan = 1,
                OlusturmaTarihi = DateTime.Now
            };
            dbo.Pano_Gorev.AddObject(gorev);
            dbo.SaveChanges();
            sresult = true;
            context.Response.Write(sresult);
        }
        else
        {
            sresult = false;
            context.Response.Write(sresult);
        }
```

The problem is on handler, because all values come as null.

```
  context.request.Form[..] //all coming as null.
```

I also tried the following :

```
context.request[..]
```

But this did not work either.

What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: What browser are you using? Check here if you meet the requirements https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility. If you don't you'll have to go old school using forms

Comment: @LiviuBoboia I am using mozilla and I used these code before in another project and it worked. However this time doesn't work. Ajax is posting formdata well, there is not a problem but on the handler, I can't reach any data or value.

Comment: That is very strange, did you make sure that the name and ids for you upload elements match the keys for the context.Request.Form[...] ?

Comment: @LiviuBoboia Yes, I checked and it is true. I think context.request.Form not enought to get data. I am trying something random like context.request.Form.GetValues (just example) but couldn't find anything. Can you vote up the question please?

Comment: do you have anything in context.Request.Form.Keys

Comment: @LiviuBoboia Yes. In FireBug answer of handler for one is ["-----------------------------8714321238031\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name"]

Comment: i meant in your handler, if you debug the application do you have anything in context.Request.Form.Keys

Comment: @LiviuBoboia I can not debug project because i am uploading documents with fileZilla and working on site. I am debugging with FireBug on the site.                                                                                    var gorevBaslik = context.Request.Form.Keys;
            sjson = sjsonSerializer.Serialize(gorevBaslik);
            context.Response.Write(sjson);
            context.Response.End();                                                             and response on Firebug is ["-----------------------------201922335925003\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. Jquery document in the project was old version and it was the problem why these codes did not work. When i update the jquery, codes work truely.

I edited some little mistakes.

In Consequence, this code can be usable and problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Use native javascript. For example this is html :

```
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
</form>
```

This is javascript :

```
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "url");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
```